# In theano, why am I getting this theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError when it's clearly connected?

Tags: theano

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/axoren1/SmokingDataProject/Rotation Test.py", line 40, in <module>
    dJ = T.grad((R(n, t) - R(n, angles)).norm(2), t)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 529, in grad
    handle_disconnected(elem)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 516, in handle_disconnected
    raise DisconnectedInputError(message)
theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable operator: Theta
```

What does this mean? Below is my code an an explanation for why I think this error is vacuous.

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import theano.tensor.nlinalg as Tn

n = 5

angles = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(n, 1)

def R(n, angles):
    sines   = T.sin(angles)
    cosines = T.cos(angles)

    def r(i, j):
        sign = -1 * -1 ** ((i + j) % 2)
        c = cosines[i - 1] * cosines[j]
        s = T.prod(sines[i:j])

        return sign * c * s

    R = T.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            T.inc_subtensor(R[i:i+1][j:j+1], r(i, j))
    for i in range(0, n - 1):
        T.inc_subtensor(R[i+1:i+2][i:i+1], sines[i])

    return R

guess = np.random.rand(n, 1)

t = T.vector("Theta")
for i in range(100):
    J = (R(n, t) - R(n, angles)).norm(2)
    dJ = T.grad((R(n, t) - R(n, angles)).norm(2), t)
    guess -= dJ.eval({t:guess})
    print J.eval({t:guess}), guess
```

As you can see, the `Theta` node is defined and used by the cost function. I don't see how the function `R` is discontinuous at all. Why is this breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to assign the result of the `inc_subtensor` calls back to `R`.

Instead of

```
T.inc_subtensor(R[i:i+1][j:j+1], r(i, j))
```

and

```
T.inc_subtensor(R[i+1:i+2][i:i+1], sines[i])
```

use

```
R = T.inc_subtensor(R[i:i+1][j:j+1], r(i, j))
```

and

```
R = T.inc_subtensor(R[i+1:i+2][i:i+1], sines[i])
```

`inc_subtensor` is a symbolic operation that returns an object representing the symbolic result of incrementing the provided subtensor by the provided value.

Comment: This answer overcomes the reported error but a further error will subsequently encountered. The second problem appears unrelated to the first so a second question should be created here if further help is required.